# odoo login microsoft 365 failed

Tags: email, odoo, microsoft365

we are facing some major probelems with odoo v13 and importing mails from microsoft365/outlook. We setup our ticket system to import e-mails and create tickets from these e-mails which works fine until today. Now odoo can't login to the e-mail accounts anymore.

We changed passwords, tried other mail accounts and only with microsoft it's not working. Other accounts work well. It seems like something on microsoft side has changed.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft deactivated base authentication, so logging in by regular credentials (loginname, password) won't work anymore. Instead you should upgrade your Odoo 13 to get the new modules for outlook/o365: `fetchmail_outlook` and `microsoft_outlook`.

To get more information just look into [this Issue](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/44943). At the end of this issue a nice finnish guy shared a little documentation how to set up the oauth2 way.

As far as i know all verions from 13 have those modules.